# Dataframe: Delete rows per index after condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe looking like this:

| ID | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Create Account |
| 100 | Verify Account |
| 100 | Deletion Request |
| 100 | E-Mail Request |
| 200 | Create Account |
| 200 | Deletion Request |
| 300 | Create Account |

Per ID, I want to delete every value after the activity "Deletion Request" (incl.) in the Activity column, so the result should look like this:

| ID | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Create Account |
| 100 | Verify Account |
| 200 | Create Account |
| 300 | Create Account |

My approach was iterating through all ID´s with `df["ID].value_counts()`, getting the indices from the first occurrence of "Deletion Request" to the end of the ID range, but I think there is a much better & quicker way to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `groupby.apply` to check if it is `Deletion Request` rows and do `cumsum` to get the following rows

```py
out = df[~(df.groupby('ID')['Activity']
           .apply(lambda g: g.eq('Deletion Request').cumsum() > 0))]
```

```
print(out)

    ID        Activity
0  100  Create Account
1  100  Verify Account
4  200  Create Account
6  300  Create Account
```

Comment: This only removes one activity succeeding the deletion request, but not more.

Comment: @ErikFubel Sorry for the misunderstanding, now updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) with condition - compare `Activity` for `Deletion Request` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with invert mask by `~`:

```
out = df[~df['Activity'].eq('Deletion Request').groupby(df['ID']).cummax()]

print (out)
    ID        Activity
0  100  Create Account
1  100  Verify Account
4  200  Create Account
6  300  Create Account
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column, map integer value for each activity:

```
(
df[activityid]=df.Activity.map({'Create Account':1,
'Verify Account':2,
'Deletion Request':3
'E-Mail Request':4}
)
```

Then create a temporary dataframe to hold the index value columns to delete

```
out=df[df.Activityid>=3].index
```

Finally, drop the rows using the drop method/

```
df.drop(index=out,inplace=True)
```